# Windows 10 Activation when swapping hard drives

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, computer-building

I'm in the process of building a new PC but slowly, as I only buy the components when I have extra cash due to overtime but because of this, it could be a few months before I have everything together.

Currently, I have a new graphics card and an SSD.  What I was thinking was that I could clone and install the SSD in my existing machine (giving me a speed boost on my existing rig) then take it out to put in as a fresh install when the new PC is together.  I will do this with a new license for Windows 10.

My question is, will Windows let me return my old HDD to the current machine (which is still fine for day to day use and older games) and still be fully activated?

Comment: So to get this straight you want to clone the ssd now, clean install it when new pc is built, and use the old hdd on the old pc again like you never took it out. If this is the case then yes, you can do that. If you don't format the hdd then you are good to go. Otherwise you have to clone back the ssd to hdd before the clean install

Comment: @D.A That's correct and great, thanks.  I do now realise I will have to clone the SSD back to HDD anyway to make sure everything is fully updated and I don't lose any of the documents created in the meantime.  If you put this in as an answer, I will accept it as correct.  Thanks.

Comment: @D.A why don't you post this as an answer? Then we can mark this question as solved.

Comment: @LPChip Just writing it down

Comment: The activation status of your Windows installation  isn't connected to the storage devices. Only retail Windows 10 licenses can be moved to new hardware that is significantly different from one another.  Your major problem won't be the activation status but getting it to actually boot.  It's not difficult but also.l not trivial to move an installation from one machine to another machine and have it actually boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done that on my Laptop and works without a problem almost 2 years now. Bought a hybrid to speed things up and keep my old HDD on a drawer. I usually swap them when I have to get the Laptop for a service and works without a problem.

So to answer your question: Yes, Windows will let you return to the old HDD and still be fully activated. Take it like your HDD failed and you bought a new hard drive, you wouldn't have to buy a new license.

The only way I can think of it might fail is if you use the Hard drives simultaneously with the same activation code (but again not sure, haven't had personal experience with that)

As I said in the comments clone back the SSD to the HDD before the clean install to be up to date. If done correctly there is nothing to worry about. Use a tool that has positive reviews and satisfied users. Don't just use the first free tool you will find.

Another idea is to use the two disks as RAID. That way everything you do on SSD will be saved on the HDD (HDD will be served as backup) so when you decide to remove the SSD you will already have the HDD updated

---

**If at any point something goes wrong** with the Windows Activation use this official Microsoft page: [Reactivating Windows 10 after a hardware change](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20530/windows-10-reactivating-after-hardware-change).

Comment: For me, replacing the HDD caused W10 to no longer be activated. That conflicts with your own test.

Comment: @Overmind how did you do it? Did the HDD fail and you did a clean install? Did you clone the disk, and how did you clone it?

Comment: @Overmind last time I did that was a week ago. Swapped the HDDs and worked like a charm.

Comment: @Overmind please read [this forum](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-3382302/cloned-activate-windows.html). Every comment says that if done properly and the two disks are not used at the same time, windows activation does not fail. There is also this page from [Microsoft: Reactivating windows 10 after hardware change](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20530/windows-10-reactivating-after-hardware-change)

Comment: It was a clean install. The old one was damaged beyond recovery. The reactivation method you mention involves an account, therefore it's not always doable.

Comment: @Overmind well nowadays Bios has the activation key saved and no need to do anything. At least on my experience when I first set up windows I used my google account to register windows (ie Microsoft Account). If needed in the future I will use the same account to recover it. Now if nothing of this applies to you then you got a special case

Comment: That only works on UEFI and as far as I recall Windows does not embed the key, the OEM does that. Simply put: If there isn’t a key already embeded, there still won’t be one after installing whatever Windows version you procure.